# Is possible know who is requesting my server through GET request using Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm implement a control of requests in my server and i need know... Is possible know who is requesting my server through GET request without use any parameter to identify the client? If it can be possible I'll improve my development considerably.

For example: Know what's the IP, MAC Address, PC/Device name and others...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on a servlet environment, and quoting from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html):

- `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`: Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request.
- `ServletRequest.getRemoteHost()`: Returns the fully qualified name of the client or the last proxy that sent the request.

There are more in the `ServletRequest` class and the `HttpServletRequest` ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)) - the class of the parameter that gets passed to the servlet service methods.

Comment: When i use this attributes the server return these values for me: `http://localhost:8080/webi/ServletMain` `RemoteAddr: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`
`RemoteHost: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`
`RemotePort: 58938` 
`RemoteUser: null` Do you know why?

Comment: It happens because i have tested in localhost, but in external communication it works "fine". Do you know why `RemoteUser` always returns `null`?

Comment: The `getRemoteUser()` method is related to servlet authentication. If you have configured servlet authentication AND the current user is authenticated, it will return a value.

Answer (score 2):

In the Servlet you can use

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

to get  the accessing machine IP and then store it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your localhost_access_log.txt in your tomcat logging directory. This is probably the best you can do without any client side code. This will show the origin IP address of the GET request though.

Comment: Very good! Another question... Do you know some way to get this information and save at my database? Thank you very much!